# Clicking on a button in a file download popup Window using watir-webdriver

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, watir, watir-webdriver

Folks,

I am having an interesting problem. I have some javascript on the webpage which opens a popup window when clicked. I am trying to find the title of the window so that I can click on that, the window has the following two buttons "Cancel" and "Save File". Here is what I am doing in my ruby code:

```
@windows = @browser.windows #this should return an array, so @windows is an array
p @windows[1] #output of this is #<Watir::Window:0x115c796cc located=true>
puts "This is the title of the second window---->"+@windows[1].title #this puts blank
```

The problem that I am seeing is why does my windows object does not have any variables when I print it out using `p @windows[1]` also why is the title not printed when I do `@windows[1].title`. My goal is click on the "Download the file" button of the popup window

This is the piece of HTML that I have:

```
<td>
   <a onclick="window.open(this.href);return false;" href="/search/searches/1563/exports/1017">6175-1017-20120418181521-karnire.eml.zip</a>
</td>
```

The other thing that I tried is doing something like this in my code:

```
@windows = @browser.windows
@browser.window(:title => @windows[1].title).use do
     @browser.button(:value => "Save File").click
end
```

for the above I get an error like this:

```
Unable to locate window "{639686d9-4641-aa41-bf6f-3ba89659d921}" (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::NoSuchWindowError)
```

Comment: can you show us the HTML that is causing the window to appear?  Is it possible this is not a new browser window but a modal javascript 'confirm' box?

Comment: @ChuckvanderLinden this is the HTML `<td>
<a onclick="window.open(this.href);return false;" href="/report/reports/1563/reports/1017">6333-33317-20134745748181521-dfrgrgr.fml.zip</a>
</td>`

Comment: You know you should be able to edit your question and put the HTML in there (formatted nicely even) yourself..

Comment: It looks like it is just opening a new window that point directly to the file to be downloaded.  I think that means the dialog you are seeing comes from the browser itself, and may be a standard download confirmation  Is it important for your test that you verify the contents of the file? or is knowing that the file-name itself is correct enough?

Comment: @ChuckvanderLinden i added more details above. It is important for me to validate the contents of the file, I have written and tested code to validate that the contents of the file are right.

Comment: pretty sure the dialog you are trying to respond to is part of the browser (e.g. at the OS level) and not part of a web-page.  See the answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd start with the information provided [here on the watir-webdriver blog](http://watirwebdriver.com/browser-downloads/)

if that does not work, then try looking at the [watir-wiki page on file downloads](http://wiki.openqa.org/display/WTR/File+Downloads)?

It's a little dated (not having been updated in a year, also using autoit not rautomation) but it might be enough to get you going.

Answer (score 0):

It might be that Watir isn't waiting for the window to load. Try putting a sleep(10) after the click.